# asp button event inside foundation modal not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, zurb-foundation

I have tried searching for a solution for this, but nothing seems to be working for me. My problem is pretty straightforward though (so, I think).

I am using foundation with asp webforms and have a reveal modal window that fires when the page is loaded.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open') });
```

The above works fine, however, any time I put an ASP button inside the modal (the one I am using, btnReset, redirects to a new page), clicking on it will not fire the event attached to it.

Code:

```
<div id="reset">
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" 
                    OnClick="btnReset_Click" OnClientClick="btnReset_Click"   
                    CssClass="button small radius alert" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Code for btnReset:

```
protected void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["userInfo"];
     cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
     Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
     Response.Redirect("LogIn.aspx");
     //Server.Transfer("LogIn.aspx");
}
```

I'm sure I am missing some here, but I'm just stumped on what I am doing wrong. How can I get an ASP button and have it fire it's event when it is inside a modal?

Comment: added requested code to op.

Comment: No, the only javascript I have is to load the modal when the page loads and a function that closes the modal attached to another button inside the modal (this works fine)

Comment: OnClientClick completely removed - same problem exists.

Comment: what does the renderd btn look like can you add that too

Answer (score 4):

I know this was asked a month ago, but I ran into the same problem and found this question with no solution.  I have found the solution over at the Foundation forums and thought I would answer it here for future reference.

This issue is with how foundation adds your modal.  When you look in your dev tools you will see that the modal, when called, is **outside** the form making the asp buttons unable to access the code behind.

This means we need to append the the modal to the form so that the buttons will access the code behind.

I tried several different ways to achieve this in the javascript using appendTo, but found the easiest method was the make foundation use the root element form.

```
$(document).foundation('reveal', { rootElement: 'form' });
```

I found that here: [Elena Zhdanova solution](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/1187-aspnetfoundation-reveal-modal)

Comment: Thanks. The syntax has slightly changed now, though. It should be `root_element` instead.

Comment: Why is this not marked as an answer? I could've missed it cause I only look for answers when I have a problem.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone new stumbling across this issue you can now add this to your reveal modal and your webforms buttons will work as intended inside the modal.

```
data-append-to="form"
```

The documentation is [here](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/reveal.html). And the credit goes to this old forum post by Lars Jensen at the bottom of the thread [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170719014019/http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/1187-aspnetfoundation-reveal-modal)